How to change Github user for Github Copilot in IntelliJ
I accidently logged into wrong github user for activating GitHub Copilot. I am not able to switch and continue to validate against the same user. Neither restart nor reinstall plugin helps here.

Took sometime but figured out. Posting the answer here hoping it will help some one.
All you have to do is , go to C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\github-copilot and remove apps.json, restart the IDE. It will prompt again to sign in at Github.

For me, I could use Tools > GitHub Copilot and then log out and log back in with a different account.

Thanks for your advice. Had the same problem but there was no apps.json under the path.
I found hosts.json and I think it's the same think. The file saved my user and the token for GitHub CoPilot. I deleted the file and voila I can finally sign in to copilot.
